# Sweeping backward through formatted stream file

Tags: io, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

More problems with formatted stream I/O. This time I scan a file opened for formatted stream access for the starts of the lines. This is completely successful. However, when I try to copy the file backwards using these markers, problems are encountered both on `ifort` and `gfortran`. The program:

```
program testpos2
   implicit none
   character(80) halfline
   character(:), allocatable :: line
   integer iunit
   integer junit
   integer i
   integer, parameter :: N = 4
   integer pos(N)
   integer size
   integer current

   open(newunit=iunit,file='testpos2.txt',status='replace')
   do i = 1, N
      write(halfline,'(*(g0))') i,' 2nd half ',i
      write(iunit,'(*(g0))') trim(halfline)
   end do
   close(iunit)
   allocate(character(len_trim(halfline)) :: line)
   open(newunit=iunit,file='testpos2.txt',status='old',access='stream',form='formatted')
   do i = 1, N
      inquire(iunit,pos=pos(i))
      read(iunit,'()')
   end do
   open(newunit=junit,file='testpos3.txt',status='replace')
   do i = N, 1, -1
      read(iunit,'(a)',pos=pos(i),advance='no',eor=10,size=size) line
      inquire(iunit,pos=current)
      write(*,'(*(g0))') 'pos(i) = ',pos(i),', current = ',current
      write(junit,'(*(g0))',advance='no') line
      do
         read(iunit,'(a)',advance='no',eor=10,size=size) line
         inquire(iunit,pos=current)
         write(*,'(*(g0))') 'pos(i) = ',pos(i),', current = ',current
         write(junit,'(*(g0))',advance='no') line
      end do
10 continue
      write(junit,'(*(g0))') line(1:size)
   end do
end program testpos2
```

Run-time output with `gfortran 8.1.0`:

```
pos(i) = 43, current = 55
pos(i) = 29, current = 41
pos(i) = 15, current = 27
pos(i) = 1, current = 13
```

Perfect! but the output file is:

```
4 2nd half 4
3 2nd half 3
4 2nd half 4
1 2nd half 1
```

Observe that the third line is the wrong one!
Run-time output with `ifort 16.0.2`:

```
pos(i) = 43, current = 55
pos(i) = 29, current = 69
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit -130, file C:\testpos2.txt
```

And the output file is binary junk after the first line.

This looks much like the result of corrupted memory, but the program seems simple enough that I can't see where corruption could occur, not to mention that both ifort and gfortran produce the expected results when the file is scanned in the forward direction. So could it be that the I/O libraries of both compilers are the ones causing corruption or is it me?

Comment: Not that it would make a lot of difference but try setting iunit and junit.

Comment: @cup I'm not sure what you mean: the `OPEN` statements with the `NEWUNIT=` *connect-specs* `set iunit` & `junit`. OK, well I tried setting `iunit=10` and `junit=11` and switched to the `UNIT=` *connect-spec* and the results were the same as before.